# Not able to run a selected suiteXmlFile via maven surefire plugin

Tags: maven, testing, maven-plugin, maven-surefire-plugin

I have a pretty simple test project setup where I have multiple suiteXmlFiles. The pom looks as follows:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>testautomation</groupId>
<artifactId>testautomation</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>

 <properties>
    <log4j.version>2.8.2</log4j.version>
    <selenium.version>2.53.0</selenium.version>
    <testng.version>6.10</testng.version>       
    <relevantcodes.version>2.41.1</relevantcodes.version>
    <aws-lambda-java-core.version>1.1.0</aws-lambda-java-core.version>
    <aws-java-sdk-dynamodb.version>1.11.139</aws-java-sdk-dynamodb.version>
    <rest-assured.verison>2.9.1-SNAPSHOT</rest-assured.verison>
    <json-path.version>2.9.0</json-path.version>
    <json.version>20160810</json.version>
    <xml-path.version>2.9.0</xml-path.version>
    <json-schema-validator.verison>2.9.0</json-schema-validator.verison>
    <poi.verison>3.15</poi.verison>
    <poi-ooxml.verison>3.15</poi-ooxml.verison>
    <poi-ooxml-schemas.version>3.15</poi-ooxml-schemas.version>
    <poi-scratchpad.version>3.2-FINAL</poi-scratchpad.version>
    <jackson-databind.version>2.8.5</jackson-databind.version>  
    <maven.compiler.plugin.version>3.6.1</maven.compiler.plugin.version>
    <opencsv>3.10</opencsv>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    <!-- <maven.jar.plugin.version>3.0.2</maven.jar.plugin.version> -->
    <maven.jar.plugin.version>2.6</maven.jar.plugin.version>
    <maven-install-plugin.version>2.5.2</maven-install-plugin.version>

     <maven-surefire-plugin.version>2.19.1</maven-surefire-plugin.version>
     <!--<maven-surefire-plugin.version>2.12</maven-surefire-plugin.version> -->
    <skipTests>false</skipTests>
     <sometest>src/test/resources/testngxmls/sometest/test1.xml</sometest>
    <smoketest>src/test/resources/testngxmls/smoketest/test2.xml</smoketest>


</properties>


<build>
    <!-- <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory> -->
    <plugins>

     <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${maven.compiler.plugin.version}</version>
            <inherited>true</inherited>
            <configuration>
                <source>${java.version}</source>
                <target>${java.version}</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>               

        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${maven.jar.plugin.version}</version>
            <inherited>true</inherited>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>test-jar</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-install-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${maven-install-plugin.version}</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>default-install</id>
                    <phase>install</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>install</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${maven-surefire-plugin.version}</version>
             <configuration>
                <skipTests>${skipTests}</skipTests>
                <suiteXmlFiles>
                    <xmlFile>${sometest}</xmlFile>
                    <xmlFile>${smoketest}</xmlFile>
                </suiteXmlFiles>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>

<dependencies>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
        <version>${selenium.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
        <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
        <version>${testng.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
        <version>${log4j.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.relevantcodes</groupId>
        <artifactId>extentreports</artifactId>
        <version>${relevantcodes.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
        <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
        <version>${poi.verison}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
        <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
        <version>${poi-ooxml.verison}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
        <artifactId>poi-ooxml-schemas</artifactId>
        <version>${poi-ooxml-schemas.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
        <artifactId>poi-scratchpad</artifactId>
        <version>${poi-scratchpad.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!--adding only required jars of AWS -->

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
        <artifactId>aws-lambda-java-core</artifactId>
        <version>${aws-lambda-java-core.version}</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
        <artifactId>aws-java-sdk-dynamodb</artifactId>
        <version>${aws-java-sdk-dynamodb.version}</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.jayway.restassured</groupId>
        <artifactId>rest-assured</artifactId>
        <version>${rest-assured.verison}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.jayway.restassured</groupId>
        <artifactId>json-path</artifactId>
        <version>${json-path.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.jayway.restassured</groupId>
        <artifactId>xml-path</artifactId>
        <version>${xml-path.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.jayway.restassured</groupId>
        <artifactId>json-schema-validator</artifactId>
        <version>${json-schema-validator.verison}</version>
        <!-- <scope>test</scope> -->
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
         <groupId>com.opencsv</groupId>
         <artifactId>opencsv</artifactId>
         <version>${opencsv}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
        <version>${jackson-databind.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.json</groupId>
        <artifactId>json</artifactId>
        <version>${json.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>

        <groupId>com.google.inject</groupId>
        <artifactId>guice</artifactId>
        <version>3.0</version>
    </dependency>

     <!-- <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-text</artifactId>
        <version>1.1</version>
    </dependency> -->
</dependencies>

<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>sonatype</id>
        <url>https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/</url>
        <snapshots />
    </repository>
</repositories>
```

With this pom.xml. I have been trying to use mvn command line to run selected suites independently, however it keeps executing all the suiteXmlFiles. The command I have used are as follows:

When I run this command `$ mvn -e clean test -Dsurefire.xmlFile=sometest` it runs sometest suite and then also runs all tests in smoketest. Similar observations with all the commands listed below.

`$ mvn -e clean test -Dsurefire.xmlFiles=sometest`

I have even tried changing the xmlFile to suiteXmlFile and file tags and running the respective commands:

`$ mvn -e clean test -Dsurefire.suiteXmlFile=sometest
$ mvn -e clean test -Dsurefire.suiteXmlFiles=sometest`

`$ mvn -e clean test -Dsurefire.suiteXmlFile=sometest
$ mvn -e clean test -Dsurefire.suiteXmlFiles=sometest`

Is there a way these tests can be run independently sticking to the suiteXmlFiles. This looks like a straightforward feature and it is puzzling why it would be so difficult to get this up and running.

Comment: you could create separate profiles for  sometest and smoketest

Comment: @nayakam I know that could be done, however, this seems like a pretty straightforward feature and I am curious to know why this would not work. Is there something fundamental that I am doing wrong?

Comment: http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/test-mojo.html#suiteXmlFiles  try with version above 2.2. HTH

Comment: @nayakam That did not work. I am already using the latest version

Answer (score 2):

Seems working fine with testng-6.13.1 and maven-surefire-plugin 2.20. Check you artifact versions or you have to pass the correct file path to Dsurefire.suiteXmlFile option.

MVN Command:

```
 mvn test -Dsurefire.suiteXmlFiles=src/test/resources/testXml1.xml
```

Output for Test Suite 1:

```
[INFO] Running TestSuite
This is TestNG-Test-Suite-First Example
[INFO] Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.345 s - in TestSuite
[INFO]
[INFO] Results:
[INFO]
[INFO] Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0
```

MVN Command:

```
 mvn test -Dsurefire.suiteXmlFiles=src/test/resources/testXml2.xml
```

Output for Test Suite 2:

```
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------
[INFO]  T E S T S
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Running TestSuite
@BeforeTest
This is TestNG-Test-Suite-Second Example
@AfterTest

[INFO] Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.399 s - in TestSuite
[INFO]
```

**Project Setup**

**pom.xml**

```
 <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
            <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
            <version>6.13.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <pluginManagement>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.1</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <source>1.8</source>
                        <target>1.8</target>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.20</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <suiteXmlFiles>
                            <suiteXmlFile>src/test/resources/testXmlAll.xml</suiteXmlFile>
                            <suiteXmlFile>src/test/resources/testXml1.xml</suiteXmlFile>
                            <suiteXmlFile>src/test/resources/testXml2.xml</suiteXmlFile>
                        </suiteXmlFiles>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </pluginManagement>
    </build>
```

**testXml1.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd" >
<suite name="test1">
    <test name="test1">
        <classes>
            <class name="TestNgSuiteFirstTest"/>
        </classes>
    </test>
</suite>
```

**testXml2.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd" >
<suite name="test2">
    <test name="test2">
        <classes>
            <class name="TestNgSuiteSecondTest"/>
        </classes>
    </test>
</suite>
```

---

**Pass the suite file as parameter**

This is just a workaround to pass the suit file as parameter

Configure property variable to point to each suite file.

```
<properties>
   <test1SuiteFile>${project.basedir}/src/test/resources/testXml1.xml</test1SuiteFile>
        <test2SuiteFile>${project.basedir}/src/test/resources/testXml2.xml</test2SuiteFile>
        <!-- Default suites -->
        <testAllSuiteFile>${project.basedir}/src/test/resources/testXmlAll.xml</testAllSuiteFile>
        <suiteFile>${testAllSuiteFile}</suiteFile>
    </properties>
```

**Update plugin:**

```
 <configuration>
     <suiteXmlFiles>
          <suiteXmlFile>${suiteFile}</suiteXmlFile>
      </suiteXmlFiles>
  </configuration>
```

**Pass the file name as parameter in  command line**

```
mvn clean test
mvn test -DsuiteFile=${test2SuiteFile}
mvn test -DsuiteFile=${test1SuiteFile},${test2SuiteFile}
```

---

Otherwise define configuration as follows and pass single file:

```
mvn test -DsuiteFile=testXml1.xml

   <configuration> 
             <suiteXmlFile>${project.basedir}/src/test/resources/${suiteFile}
                            </suiteXmlFile>
  </suiteXmlFiles>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Weird enough, it seems to work perfectly fine when you hardcode the entire xml file path. However, when you parametrize using <properties>, it does not seem to work. For example, using your pom.xml use the parametrized property value for the suiteXmlFiles value and try running the mvn command using the suitename and you will run into the same issue.

Comment: Is the <suitXmlFile> suppose to contain all the parametrized values or just ${suiteFile}, what does the content of testXmlAll and other xml look like. I tried following what you said but it is still not working. Could you update your comments so that it reflects the exact state of your code including the contents of the xml files.

Comment: Updated the answer, This just a work around, Just set the path in variable then pass only file name as parameter rather than full path.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help! It did work for me, however due to some requirement change at work I started using maven profiles.